# Erro na geração de bookdown

Tags: r, rmarkdown

Estou tentando criar um bookdown (do pacote https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/). Quando vou criar o book ele retorna o erro abaixo. Já setei os parametros: `output: bookdown::gitbook` e
`site: bookdown::bookdown_site`. Além disso apaguei o arquivo main várias vezes, e não resolveu a questão. Alguém sabe como ajudar?

```
Error in render_book("index.Rmd", output_format = output_format, envir = envir) : 
The file _main.Rmd exists. Please delete it if it was automatically
generated, or set a different book_filename option in _bookdown.yml. 
If you are sure it can be safely deleted, please set the option 'delete_merged_file' 
to true in _bookdown.yml.
Calls: <Anonymous> ... <Anonymous> -> in_dir -> render_book_script -> 
render_book
Execu��o interrompida

Exited with status 1.
```

Answer (score 3):

O erro sugere para você deletar o arquivo `_main.Rmd` e colocar `delete_merged_file = TRUE`.

Caso não possa deleter o arquivo `_main.Rmd`, utilize um diferente `book_filename`no `_bookdown.yml`